# Getting Attribute for Homepage

Tags: templating, field

I have created a field for the homepage called icon_font.  I now want to access that field in my template.  What is the best way to do that?  Do I have to use a for loop (even though there is only one homepage)?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Moshe

**EDIT:**
Note, the template in question is NOT my homepage template, but rather a different template which relates to a different section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to get your homepage entry:

```
{% set homepage = craft.entries.slug('homepage').first() %}
```

Then, you can call the field you need from `homepage`:

```
{{homepage.entry_icon}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your homepage is a Single section and you've checked the "This is for the homepage" checkbox in the section's settings, all you should need to do is:

```
{{ entry.icon_font }}
```

From the template you specified in the section's settings.

Comment: That works on my homepage template, but I am trying to access this from a different page template related to a different section (sorry I didn't mention that above).